# Missing imgur image

Tags: support, images

This question:

[How can I finish this "peeled" drywall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1376/how-can-i-finish-this-peeled-drywall)

has it's image missing:

> [image: dry wall oh noooes]

The link is `https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSl1E.jpg`

I tried editing the question but as you can see here the image hasn't shown up.

Comment: "**How long do you keep the images?**
As long as images are getting at least 1 view every 6 months, they will stick around forever. After that, your image may be removed to create more space for newer images." [Source](http://imgur.com/faq#long).  Is it possible that we could lose more images, if they are not viewed?

Comment: @Tester101 - This shouldn't happen. The images uploaded to `i.stack.imgur.com` *should* be immune to that rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image in question probably was uploaded through the original imgur service independent of `i.stack.imgur`. However, removing the stack still results in a broken image - so I'm under the impression that the user's original image has decayed on its own.

It would probably wise to contact the user and ask if they still have the image that they can provide (and upload through `i.stack.imgur`).

Comment: Ah - do you know the approximate date of when `i.stack.imgur` started so I can just contact the OP rather than bothering the team? I've left a comment for the OP, lets hope he logs into the site soon.

Comment: @ChrisF The global replace hit all images posted starting from August 17th.